# not able to run pig on windows 7 using cygwin

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-pig

I configured pig as directed in the documentation. 
Enviornment: Windows 7, Hadoop-0.20.2, pig 0.13.0, Cygwin

But when i type pig (mapreduce) on the command prompt it just displays below thing. I am not sure whether pig is started or not. I don't see GRUNT shell to execute script.

Btw, Hadoop is running on the same node.

Can someone please help?

$ pig
Find hadoop at /hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop
dry run:
HADOOP_CLASSPATH: C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\conf;C;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib\tools.jar;C;C:\cygwin64\hadoop-0.20.2\conf;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\accumulo-core-1.5.0.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\accumulo-fate-1.5.0.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\accumulo-server-1.5.0.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\accumulo-start-1.5.0.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\accumulo-trace-1.5.0.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\avro-1.7.5.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\avro-mapred-1.7.5.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\avro-tools-1.7.5-nodeps.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\groovy-all-1.8.6.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\hbase-0.94.1.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\js-1.7R2.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\json-simple-1.1.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\piggybank.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar;C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0\lib\zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:C:\cygwin64\PIG-01~1.0/pig-withouthadoop-h2.jar:
HADOOP_OPTS: -Xmx1000m  -Dpig.log.dir=C:\cygwin64\PIG-01~1.0\logs -Dpig.log.file=pig.log -Dpig.home.dir=C:\cygwin64\PIG-01~1.0\
HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS: -Xmx1000m  -Dpig.log.dir=C:\cygwin64\PIG-01~1.0\logs -Dpig.log.file=pig.log -Dpig.home.dir=C:\cygwin64\PIG-01~1.0\
/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop jar C:\cygwin64\PIG-01~1.0/pig-withouthadoop-h2.jar

when i run in debug mode, i see this exception. This is because Hadoop Jar is not set.

```
localhsot@mymachine~
$ echo $PIG_INSTALL
C:\cygwin64\pig-0.13.0

localhsot@mymachine~
$ export PIG_INSTALL=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/pig-0.13.0

localhsot@mymachine~
$ export HADOOP_INSTALL=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/hadoop-0.20.2/

localhsot@mymachine~
$ export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_INSTALL/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin


$ pig
14/08/26 14:05:12 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
14/08/26 14:05:12 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
14/08/26 14:05:12 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2014-08-26 14:05:12,998 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.                                                                                                                                                  13.0 (r1606446) compiled Jun 29 2014, 02:27:58
2014-08-26 14:05:12,998 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error message                                                                                                                                                  s to: C:\cygwin64\home\chparekh\pig_1409076312996.log
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/map                                                                                                                                                  reduce/task/JobContextImpl
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil.<clinit>(PigStatsUtil.java                                                                                                                                                  :68)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:643)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                                                                                  java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                                                                                  sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.Jo                                                                                                                                                  bContextImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer below link for the same, i hope this will help you.
http://abhijitsureshshingate.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/code-debug-test-apache-pig-scripts-using-eclipse-on-windows/

Comment: this is through eclipse. i want to run it through cygwin command prompt

Comment: i guess error is at this line from above output. but not sure how to fix it. /hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop jar C:\cygwin64\PIG-01~1.0/pig-withouthadoop-h2.jar